# What is the benefit of semantic tags?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I'm following a tutorial series on web development. While I already have a basic understanding of HTML and how to use it to structure a page, I'm indulging myself and watching the very beginner tutorials. The funny thing is, in these tutorials the author is using tags like `address` and `cite`. When he describes why one should use these tags, he explains it only as "semtantics."

While I feel like these tags may have been more prevalent ten years ago, I never run across anyone using them besides this guy. Given he is professional, I'm now conflicted on whether or not its really necessary to use them. What is the benefit?

Comment: This, like most “semantic” questions, calls for opinions and speculations, though it might be answered by references to specifications and drafts, which contain rather abstract and vague descriptions that call for interpretations and views. So it’s really not constructive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the current [HTML5.1 specification nightly](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/) (as modern as it gets):

The [address element](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#the-address-element) is valid perfectly fine to use and so is the [cite](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-cite-element) element. While a lot of sites tend to mostly use tags like `div` and `span` you can feel safe to use both `address` and `cite` .

I think it's good practice that will help you later when you have to read your HTML again to insert changes. It improves accessibility of your document as well as lets parsers other than browsers understand it better.

(Note, [address](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#h-7.5.6) and [cite](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/text.html#h-9.2.1) are legal in the old HTML specification too)

Answer (score 0):

The benefit of semantic tags is that they give your html some structure - by using them you are encoding meaning into your html that can be useful in all kinds of areas.  Search engines often use semantic tags to assist in ranking pages, to use a simple example.  Whilst it might not always seem necessary, it is good to get into the habit of using them wherever possible.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, and especially that HTML 5.1 resource. Thank you for better explaining the benefits Mat. Another unrelated question if I may, should I use the pre tag to format my paragraphs or just try and use br more often? Is there any benefit either way?

Comment: @Tyler if you found Mat's answer "useful" for your issue (which your comment indicates) you can consider upvoting it. This is how in StackOverflow we indicate usefulness normally (and not comments).

Comment: I would generally suggest you use CSS to format paragraphs.  Pre and br have their uses, but they are there again for specific reasons (ie br for breaking lines and pre for preformatted code).  Generally, I don't use either.